# container from top to bottom matching nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

setting up the basics for a website (just started learning last week or so) and so far I have this side nav bar and its doing what I want it to, minus one thing. I would like for there to be a container to be the same color as the side nav bar i currently have but the same width and to extend from the top to the bottom of the page regardless of how long the page is.

Here is the code and a jsfiddle of what im working on: http://jsfiddle.net/A977A/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id"sideContainer">
  <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Post </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Type 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Type 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Type 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

also I was wondering if there was a way to do the popout of the sub menus in plain css instead of JS? (the JS i didnt bother to get to work on that site since its not really my question)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to add = to your div:

```
<div id="sideContainer">
```

Then add this to #sideContainer in you CSS file:

```
background-color: #666;
height: 100%;
```

Giving height the value of 100% sets it to the height of the browser window.

Comment: Yea this is what I thought though for some reason it doesnt show up!

Comment: Hmmm... I got it to work in [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sjruprecht/bLsmQ/) Did you want it to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

To do the popout of the sub menus in plain css instead of JS, change

```
ul.MenuBarVertical ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible {
  left: 0;
}
```

to

```
ul.MenuBarVertical li:hover ul {
  left: 0;
}
```